# MongoDB updateOne() $inc works in playground but not in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I don't get my updateOne() method working in nodeJS, although it works in MongoDB playground.
With a vote function I'm trying to update 'score' in the photos array.

This is my code:

```
await collection.updateOne(
  { username: imageCreator, photos: { $elemMatch: { date: imageId } } },
  { $inc: { "photos.$.score": 1 } },
  ( error, result ) => {
    if (error) console.log( error );
    console.log( result );
    console.log( `user ${voter} voted for ${imageId}` );
    db.close();
  }
);
```

And the answer:

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 0
}
```

My Document looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62309da4210134409996ea87"
  },
  "username": "testuser",
  "email": "user@test.com",
  "password": "encryptedPassword",
  "photos": [
    {
      "date": 1647353973989,
      "username": "testuser",
      "imageUrl": "userImageUrl",
      "title": "imageTitle",
      "score": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help, I'm slowly turning insane.

Comment: The main reason I can think is the query not maching the document. There's two possibility. You probably already printed imageCreator and imageId variables, right?

My suggestion to you is: make your code to update the document without any variable first (hardcode). If it works you don't have any connection issue on Node.

Confirm here if you already did that. If you did, probably the variables are wrong. The dummy way to test it is to print if the hardcoded variable is equals to what you are trying to use (possible invisible chars). Depends where these variables are coming from.

Comment: Try using this syntax: `const updateResult = await collection.updateOne(...`, without the _callback_. This code needs to be within an `async` function. And, put the update statement in a `try-catch` block. As such your update statement works fine in NodeJS program. An example, https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/updateOne/

Answer (score 0):

As 
[Lucas Soares](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6105830/lucas-soares) mentioned, I tried hardcoding the variables and it worked. Apprently my imageId variable was a 'string' whereas it should've been a 'number'.

Thanks for helping me out, I wouldn't have realised otherwise!